# Shared memory initialization problem (c)

Tags: c, initialization, init, shared-memory

I'm working with shared memory segments and came across this bizzare problem.

I am trying to share a struct between many processes:

```
struct shmstruct{
    int pid[50];
    char user[50][10];
};

struct  shmstruct *shmobj;
void    *shmp;

int main()
{
    //server creates shared memory
    if((shmid = shmget((key_t)1234,sizeof(struct shmstruct),0666|IPC_CREAT)) == -1){
        fprintf(stderr,"shmget failed\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    //server attaches shared memory segment to pointer (void *)
    if((shmp = shmat(shmid,(void *) 0,0)) == (void *)-1){
        fprintf(stderr,"shmat failed\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    //structure is now linked with shared memory pointer
    printf("Memory attached at %X\n",shmp);
    shmobj = (struct shmstruct *)shmp;

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        if(shmobj->pid[i]!=0)
            printf("shminit:i:%d user:%s pid:%d\n", i, shmobj->user[i], shmobj->pid[i]);
}
```

But whenever I create and attach the shared memory segment, shmobj->pid[1] is already initialized with the value 2673!

The result of printf is ALWAYS:

```
shminit:i:1 user: pid:2673
```

Any ideas on why this is happening?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shared memory segments don't necessarily disappear when all processes detach from them. There's a good chance that your server is simply attaching to a segment that already exists.

`IPC_CREATE` doesn't *force* creation, it *allows* creation if the segment does not yet exist.

You can look into using `shm_unlink()` to properly remove shared memory segments, or the command line `shmdel` to test this will work.

Comment: Thank you very much for your insight! It seems that IPC_PRIVATE can ensure that I get a fresh new shm segment. Can I get a confirmation on that?

Comment: @Littledot, I think from memory that will work if you create the segment first then fork the children. Otherwise, there's no way to actually _share_ the memory.

Comment: that is exactly what I'm doing. Forking children and sharing memory with thier parents. Sorry for not putting that in.